# request.env['omniauth.oauth'] returns nil

Tags: omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I am using the **omniauth-google-oauth2** gem to authorise google accounts, and getting the authorisation code, but getting the **request.env['omniauth.auth']** as **nil** even after upgrading the gem to latest version.

```
ruby_version: 2.4.9
rails _version: 4.2.8
```

My Gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth', '1.9.1'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '1.7.0'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '0.8.0'
```

omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'MY_GOOGLE_SECRET',  {
    scope: 'email, profile',
    access_type: "offline",
    approval_prompt: "force",
    prompt: 'select_account',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google-oauth2/callback'
  }
```

end

routes.rb

```
get 'auth/google_oauth2/callback', to: 'social_accounts#create_account'
```

socual_accounts_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::SocialAccountsController < ApplicationController

def create_account
  request_params = request.env["omniauth.auth"] # gives nil
end

end
```

And is it possible to get the access_token and refresh_token from authorisation code ? That will also help a lot

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find the issue?

Comment: Yes, as I said request.env['omniauth.auth'] is always nil

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this recently in one of our applications, so for future generations…

Check the version of `oauth2` in your `Gemfile.lock`. Ours had been updated from 1.4.10 to 2.0.5 during a `bundle update`. We tried upgrading to the latest (v2.0.7) and downgrading to the first tag on 2 (v2.0.0) but no luck.

**Locking `oauth2` to 1.4.10**, solved our issue with `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` being `nil`.

There were [a lot of changes](https://gitlab.com/oauth-xx/oauth2/-/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#200-2022-06-21) that went into 2.0.0, so it's hard to say which one broke this.